# When is better to use CPU or I/O intensive code in child processes [ C++ ]

Tags: c++, process

I got an exam question and didn't know answer.
The task was:

---

A programmer would like to create a very fast application, hence it organizes its software in 13 processes (a parent and 12 children), all running in parallel. 
Child threads are very :

1. I/O-intensive, hence make very frequent use of system calls (read/write from files/pipes/sockets, write on standard output, etc.)
2. CPU intensive, hence make very frequent use of system calls:

Describe when this would be a good choice, when this would be a bad choice, and motivate your answer.

---

Number 1 and 2, are different questions. So answer should be for both. Good and bad sides of I/O intensive, good and bad sides of CPU intensive. 
* Sorry for inappropriate topic, I changed it. 
* "Child Threads" was on exam paper. So I copied it. I think, my professor wanted to write "process"

---

Thank you

Comment: I guess they're trying to get you to explain that if there is an io bottleneck or cpu bottleneck adding additional processes won't improve performance

Comment: 1) Thread and processes are different things. A better formulation would be that a process is split into 12 threads. 2) _CPU intensive, hence make very frequent use of system calls_ — I don't follow the implication here. CPU intensive should imply high CPU load, not calls of syscalls.

Comment: What do you mean by "instead of equal parents and children"? -- are you talking about multi-processing vs multi-threading? Or are you talking about 1-parent-process-12-child-processes vs 12-parent-processes-12-child-processes? The latter doesn't make much sense but is closer to your wording.

Comment: @DanielLangr I guess OP meant "1. I/O-intensive, hence make very frequent use of **async non-blocking** system calls 2. CPU-intensive, hence make very frequent use of **blocking** system calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My professor helped me with answer.

1. Actually, it was better to have 13 cores in PC, when it was using CPU intensive code
2. The problem was in time delay, when it has I/O intensive code. So it is better to have less cores to use them perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-threading and multi-processing is always best when it is embarrassingly parallel so each thread or process does unrelated to other thread work and is worst when threads try to share same resource.

> 1. I/O-intensive, hence make very frequent use of system calls
>      (read/write from files/pipes/sockets, write on standard output,
>      etc.)

Good idea to have such processes is when each process does I/O (reads from and/or writes to) with different media. Bad idea is when these try to use same media and so are waiting after each other.

On older media where the device has to move reading/writing heads between several tracks it can seriously hinder the performance.

> 2. CPU intensive, hence make very frequent use of system calls

Here is limitation how lot of processor cores the system has. Best case is to have one CPU intensive process per processor core. So if these processes share same core then it is worst and when these each run on different core then it is best.

The overheads from creating processes, frequent context switching between processes and communication between processes on same core are actually causing multiprocessing on single core to perform worse than same calculations done by single process (I assume in hands of master on both cases).

Often multiprocessing is not done only because of performance considerations. The more frequent reason is that the architecture consisting of smaller modules is cleaner and quality of such modules is simpler to test  and ensure in separation.

Comment: I would amend #2 to include "bad idea when the number of cores is less than the number of intensive processes.  The overhead of frequent context switches will take away from actual computation work."

Comment: Sorry, but I have some questions. For example, why is worst when it shares same cores. Is it takes more time or something else?

Comment: Thank you, for your help. I understand you, but the correct answer was for cpu intensive process. I think, out of topic about I/O intensive. The problem of I/O intensive is time delay. So if we have less cores, Cpu will change tasks and will not stay and wait answer for first task, for example. So please add this, and I will tick it as a correct answer)

Comment: What you call as "change tasks" are more commonly called as "context switches". I already wrote that these are main cost in CPU-intensive multiprocessing.